# a tag :before element to produce hover effect over image and still be clickable?

Tags: css

So what I want to achieve is an image wrapped in a link. This link will have a psuedo element :before that produces a black overlay on hover. This image should remain clickable. However, no matter what I do the pseudo element won't position above the image.

```
<a href="http://google.com">
  <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">
</a>

a {
 position: relative;
}

a:before {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 99999999;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 content: "";
 background-color: black;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

http://codepen.io/acha5066/pen/LVvmKG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `<a>` a `display: block;` in the CSS as well.

Using your code, this caused the image to be covered with a black box that was still clickable.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `a` elements are inline by default.

And that's problematic, because [`top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#position-props) specify how far the absolutely positioned box's margin edge is offset below the edge of the box's containing block. And the [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details) is calculated as follows:

> If the element has `position: absolute`, the containing block is
>   established by the nearest ancestor with a [`position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position) of
>   `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`, in the following way:
>
> - In the case that the ancestor is an inline element, the containing block is the bounding box around the padding boxes of the first and
>     the last inline boxes generated for that element. In CSS 2.1, if the
>     inline element is split across multiple lines, the containing block is
>     undefined.
> - Otherwise, the containing block is formed by the [padding edge](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-edge) of the ancestor.

Therefore, add this:

```css
a { display: block; }
```

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVwHC.jpg">
</a>
```